# Update object's property if not null, or create new object if null then set property

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to find the nicest, cleanest way to update a nullable object property that is also an object. Psuedo code:

```
class MyClass {
   val myNullableProperty: MyPropertyClass? 
}
```

Here's the ugly solution I have so far:

```
val myProperty = myClass.myNullableProperty ?: MyPropertyClass() // MyPropertyClass has default constructor values so this is fine instantiating like this in my example
myProperty.name = "Name" 
myClass.myNullableProperty = myProperty
```

This just feels not the best way of doing this. I feel there's some sort of solution using let/apply/with/run etc. - it feels wasteful to define the local variable `myProperty` like that, and then set it to `myNullableProperty` later.

I'm looking for something where I can either retrieve the existing property , or create the new property, and then immediately set the value on that property.

Answer (score 1):

Assign the value to itself, or a new instance if it's null:

```
myClass.myNullableProperty = myClass.myNullableProperty?: MyPropertyClass()
```

If you want to avoid further null checks:

```
myClass.myNullableProperty = (myClass.myNullableProperty?: MyPropertyClass()).apply{ 
    name = "Name" 
}
```

If access to the property is single-threaded, you could avoid all unnecessary assignments this way:

```
if (myClass.myNullableProperty == null)
    myClass.myNullableProperty = MyPropertyClass()
myClass.myNullableProperty!!.name = "Name"
```

Comment: Some good thoughts here... I think I like the apply version, I almost came to this solution... forgot about the brackets around the whole elvis operator expression. The second solution you offer is good too, however I think I just hate using !! ... even when I'm certain it's null, it just feels dirty!

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna make it more kotlin-y:

```
myClass.myNullableProperty?.let {
   it.name = "Name"
} ?: run {
   myClass.myNullableProperty = MyPropertyClass().apply {
      name = "Name"
   }
}
```

Comment: `let` returns null if you don't specify a return value, so the run function would happen regardless of whether the myNullableProperty is null. You would need to replace let with apply or return some non-null value. But this isn't a DRY solution anyway.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I don't think that's quite right.. in this instance run will only happen if myNullableProperty is null... the return value of the let is only relevant if there's an aassignment, e.g. `val myLetReturnVariable = myClass.myNullableProperty?.let { // etc.`

Comment: I think this solution works, although as @Tenfour04 mentions it isn't dry with the duplicate name assignment... good suggestion!

Comment: @Tenfour04 example does look more concise but I don't like the idea of assigning the object to itself again unnecessarily, just a personal preference.

Comment: Test it if you don't believe me. The `?:` follows the `let` statement, which returns null here, so the `run` block is guaranteed to run every time. Put a `println()` statement in `run` and see.

Comment: `run` would only run if `myClass.myNullableProperty` was null, It wouldn't run if `myClass.myNullableProperty` != null. I thought that was the whole point of this? to find a nice way of handling if `myClass.myNullableProperty` was or wasn't null

Comment: @Tenfour04 have you tested though? We (me and blue jones) are right, the run will not run if myNullableProperty is not null... yes, the let returns something, but that something is the last line of the let, which in this case actually returns `Unit` and not `null`. You CAN make run run, by simply typing 'null` as the last line of the let.

Comment: I did test it, but apparently I did something wrong because I just tested it again and you're right.